# Why is incorrect passsword check slow?

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, password

Observed it many times on many Ubuntu versions. If you type wrong password either in UI mode or in terminal, it takes little more time before it declares incorrect password.

Correct password check is almost instantaneous, but incorrect password takes slightly longer. Its not lot of time, but still lot more than correct password.

Why is it so?

Comment: To make guessing, even if automated, to slow to be possible???

Comment: Interesting idea, but its not slow enough - delay is there, but not enough to defeat automated tools

Comment: Because it has to probe several probable methods and every fail takes time (you can store a pwd with several methods)?

Comment: This has been answered any number of times: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/712339/why-should-checking-a-wrong-password-take-longer-than-checking-the-right-one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9163405/why-is-sudo-slow-when-password-is-incorrect http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40954/how-does-one-change-the-delay-that-occurs-after-entering-an-incorrect-password - you can find many instances of this question in [su], [unix.se], [sf], etc.

Comment: How can I switch it off?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Marc already mentioned, this mechanism should slow down automated password guesses.

Linux normally uses `pam_unix` as module to check passwords of local users. The default of this (and many other authentication modules) is to

> [...] request a delay-on-failure of the order of two second.

as described in the [man page of pam_unix](http://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_unix) (see parameter `nodelay`)

Consequently, an attacker is considerably slowed down (no more than 30 guesses per minute). Some implementations also increase the delay until the correct password is entered).

Answer (score 1):

It's a security feature to prevent, or at least slow down, brute force or dictionary attempts to crack the password.

The difference in the delay between accepting a password and not accepting it may seam small if you are typing those passwords by hand. But, without this security feature an automated system could try thousands of passwords a second.

There is more detail in this question on stackoverflow:
[Why should checking a wrong password take longer than checking the right one?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/712339/2170493)